# Does Stim work if some syndromes are only measured every 2 rounds?

Tags: error-correction, stim

I am interested in translating something to Stim so that it can run faster. The QEC code that I am trying to implement includes some syndromes that are only measured every 2 rounds. They are obtained by taking the parity between some gauge operators from the odd rounds and some gauge operators from the even rounds.

When building the decoder graph, the old implementation handles these special syndromes by repeating their measurements from the (2n)th round in the (2n + 1)th round. So that the decoder graph has the same structure as if all syndromes are measured every round.

If I specify this code in a Stim circuit, will it work? Stim gives users lots of freedom in specifying the circuit, so I think it will probably work better than the old implementation described above. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Stim can handle this case. If you declare a `DETECTOR` over measurements that are two rounds apart, it will be handled just like any other detector.

To be honest, after dealing with codes that use pair measurements instead of unitary interactions, comparing measurements two rounds apart sounds downright *soothing*. Your only worry should be whether or not the detectors you declare are interlockocking in the correct way for matching to be possible (assuming you want to decode using e.g. pymatching).

An example of what can be done. The detectors in the honeycomb code are made up of 12 measurements spaced between 2 and 5 cycles apart depending on the stabilizer. From https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.11845 :

> [image]

Another example of what can be done. The detectors in the pair measurement surface code are made up of 14 measurements scattered over 9 layers of measurements. From https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.12780 :

> [image]

I hope these scary diagrams have removed your fear of comparing two rounds apart. Or, at least, replaced them with a new fear.